# firefox certificate manager tab Authentication Decisions does not let remove decisions

Tags: firefox, security, certificate

On firefox I cannot select which certificate to use when entering some sites that require certificate.

I have found some posted answers to similar questions explaining how to use the certificate manager settings tab Authentication Decisions to remove them from there.

I go to Settings - Privacy and Security - Manage Certificates

I then select the tab Authentication Decisions.

I cannot remove any of the site decisions that have been remembered.

My question is if there exists any security setting that prevents me (protects me from) changing any certificate configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test since I don't have multiple certificates for any one site,
but I can list various methods that were proposed for this problem.

- Open in Firefox `about:preferences#privacy`, scroll down to "History",
  click "Clear History..." and clear "Active logins".
- In `about:config` :

  - Ensure `security.default_personal_cert` is set to "Ask Every Time"
  - Set `security.remember_cert_checkbox_default_setting` to "false".